# jqGrid modal edit save only changed data and marked edited row?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use jqGrid 4.9.3-pre - free jqGrid by Oleg. I edit data using the model window "Form Editing". The data get from the server.
**datatype: "json"** with **loadonce: false**, **paging of data don't use**
I use a standard table. Just call "Form Editing" ondblClickRow.

```
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
  $(this).jqGrid('setSelection', rowid)
           .jqGrid("editGridRow", rowid, { 
    recreateForm: true,
    width: 1000,
    height: "auto"});
    }
```

Two questions:

1. Mark the row when has been edited.
   [image]
2. When you edit the data and press the button Save. How do I send the data that has been modified data to the server?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. What you mean under "Mark the row"? Select the row? It's selected by default during editing. In general there are many options to start form editing: `navGrid`, `formatter: "actions"`, direct call of `editGridRow` inside of `ondblClickRow` or `onSelectRow`,... One can use different select or multiselect options. For example `singleSelectClickMode: "selectonly"` can be helpful. The next problem: you write about "Save" button. Which one (from `navGrid`, `formatter: "actions"`, your custom button, ...).

Comment: How you use jqGrid (`datatype: "local"`, `datatype: "json"` with `loadonce: true`, ...)? Do you use local paging of data? There are no standard way of implementing "modified data" especially for form editing and multipaging. Why you want to edit *multiple rows locally*? It has many disadvantages in error processing and I personally use only saving of every row separately.

Comment: datatype: "json" with loadonce: false, paging of data don't use

Comment: Do you want to edit multiple rows or if you write row you mean the **field** of the editing row: the value from the column? Please insert more code. You can register onfocus event on every editable field and set CSS on the field for example after editing. You can compare the content of every row with original content and set classes.

Comment: After editing the line, if the data has been modified, then make a mark

Comment: How to get colmodel param in "editmodjqGrid"? I can usually get this: $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam") OR $(this)[0].p . But in FormEdit Nav on another like. I saw you function getFormData (); in jqGrid. P.S. если не понятно будет, позже создам темку на русском stackoverflow и отпишу вас. Спасибо

Comment: comparing removing non-modified data before sending seems to me separate question. You can use `onclickSubmit` callback or `serializeEditData` to modify posted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your question interesting and so I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClickMarkEdited.htm), which demonstrates one of the possible implementation of making edited field of form editing. The results looks like on the picture below

[image]

The corresponding code is inside of `beforeShowForm` callback:

```
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    var $self = $(this),
        myMarker = "<span class='mychanged-item fa fa-lg fa-arrow-circle-o-left' style='display:none;border-radius:6px;background-color:LightGreen;'></span>";
    $form.find(".FormElement").focusout(function () {
        var colName = $(this).attr("name"),
            rowid = $form.find("input[name='" + $self[0].id + "_id" + "']")
                    .val(),
            oldValue = $self.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, colName),
            $myMarker = $(this).closest("td")
                        .next("td")
                        .find("span.mychanged-item");
        if ($(this).val() !== oldValue) {
            $myMarker.css("display", "");     // show
        } else {
            $myMarker.css("display", "none"); // hide
        }
    }).each(function () {
        $(this).closest("td")
            .after("<td style='width:15px'>" + myMarker + "</td>");
    });
}
```

Comment: Oleg please see the continuation [http://ru.stackoverflow.com](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486912/jqgrid-form-editing-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-postdata-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)